# Unknown memory usage/leak JDK-8-265 and Wildfly 20

Tags: jsf, memory-leaks, view-scope

I'm a bit of a novice with JDK memory and ran into an issue with what seems like very large lists not being freed when no longer used. We use jdk8.265 with wildfly 20 using JSF (mojarra-2.1.29-11) with beans using a view scope configured by faces-config.xml. We use G1GC.

We have one bean that can sometimes load a VERY large list of custom objects. It's only about 40k records, but size maybe 50MB.

As I refresh the page that gets the list (browser ctrl-R) I see the heap memory grow in the old gen. It will sometimes go down a little, but doesn't really get GC'd. I can push the Perform GC button in visualVM and that helps a little.

Anyway, I keep reloading and it keeps growing. I navigate away from page and come back, still grows. In the picture below you can see the memory usage with reloads at 1). After 1, I navigate to other view scoped pages. Forcing a GC did not change anything. At 2) I logout, then 3) I force GC.

So the question is, why would the memory not be marked as free after reloading or navigating away from the bean? I have no finalize methods on the beans and we set no session vars. It almost looks like wildfly is hanging onto multiple copies of the bean/list until I logout.

Any ideas what we are missing?

Thank you!

[image: Memory Usage]

Comment: You probably have a memory leak. Learn how to capture and analyze heap dumps to identify the instances and what is referring them. It is unlikely that this question will be answered because you would need to provide a lot more details.

Comment: Is `OpenTracing` being used? ... if so, [this WildFly bug](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-qx3p-9mmp-4v8h) could be the issue. Other than that, as the first comment said, far more information would be need, as there are _many_ ways that memory leaks could occur.

Comment: No opentracing. Just JSF. The large datatable is being saved by io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl#1. That has all of the space. We just can't see why it keeps the datatable in memory again and again. No binding to the bean. It's an old icefaces ace:datatable.

Comment: The bean pulls the data from the DB into a list, and the ace:datatable value resolves to that list. Maybe the old icefaces code (I believe it's a very old primefaces clone) saves some state in session and doesn't let it go? STATE_SAVING_METHOD=server.